# How to make all items set to taxable on WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

Hello I am hoping to make all the products on my WooCommerce set to taxable instead of individually changing each one, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for letting us know. Good luck!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Web Apps Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

In tax section, 'tax options' tab, select 'No, I will enter prices exclusive of tax'.

Then in standard rates, or what ever tax rules you have add them. There will be options to show prices in shop/cart pages including tax.

So, tax will be calculated and shown in list pages too, but you don't have to add in individually.

For better understanding of how woocommerce tax works, you can check their [doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/), It is well explained.